# How do I make an object fit into a nonuniformly shaped container?

Tags: unity-game-engine, object

first time user of Unity here. I have here a cup object and a separate object (blue cylinder) meant to act as liquid in the cup (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk5Si.jpg). I've been trying to find a way to make the "liquid" model fit to the bounds of the cup like a liquid would so that its not just kinda sitting in the middle of the cup. There is also a script on the cylinder that simulates pouring when the bottle is held over the cup that causes it to steadily expand in the y-direction from basically no height to the full height of the cup. I don't know if this would cause any issues with making the model fit the container in the x and z directions.

I'm not too great at coding yet and I haven't been able to find instructions for anything similar to this. I'm limited to using base unity stuff and free assets, nothing paid for. Any help you guys could provide would be much appreciated, thanks for your time.

I found some code that kinda looked like it could help and tried implementing it but long story short it didn't. I'm not experienced enough to know what about it caused the problem, I can't even really describe what was wrong other than that it didn't fit the bounds of the cup like I wanted. Sorry for not having more useful info here but I'm super lost at this point. Maybe its a simple fix and I'm just that dumb.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is actually a shader. Open your preferred modeling program and make a slightly scaled down version of the cup and make it solid and place it directly in the cup.

After that you need to make a shader that uses a world position node and a step node that feed into the alpha to make the top part invisible, you can control the height of your liquid with a float connected to the step node.

Since you are new, if you are confused by what I just said; look up "Unity liquid shader" on google and you'll get some nice results.